# php gzopen function is echoing the file

Tags: php, file, file-io, gzip

I am trying to update a file from an external server periodically, it works, but it prints the file with no line breaks above the website theme/content when it is updated. The file is not printed when I comment out the call to this function.

```
 public function updateWhazzup($url) {
      $fp = gzopen('tmp/whazzup/whazzup.txt.gz', 'w');
      if($fp!=false){
           gzwrite($fp, readgzfile($url));
      }
      gzclose($fp);
 }
```

Comment: Previously I used another gzopen for the second argument in the gzwrite and echo'ed the file. But I changed it a little and now it's like I've gotten rid of the echo but it is still there invisible. I've never seen anything like this I'm stumpped

Comment: Is it possible to change stdout somehow maybe??

Answer (score 0):

readgzfile() is meant to output it in browser and return the number of bytes. I used gzencode and gzdecode and a file_put_contents instead